# Get each path as list from tree

Tags: java, algorithm

Hi I have something like

```
public class Child {
    private String id;
    private List<Child> children;
}
```

an example on what it might look like in JSON:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "1_1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "1_1_1"
                },{
                    "id": "1_1_2",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": "1_1_2_1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },{
            "id": "1_2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "1_2_1",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": "1_2_1_1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I try to get a list of each path but can't find a way

I would like to obtain a List of CustomChild

CustomChild being:

```
public class CustomChild {
    private String id;
    private CustomChild child;
}
```

At the end the list should look like:
with each element is a path of my tree

```
[
    {
        "id":"1",
        "child": {
            "id": "1_1",
            "child": {
                "id": "1_1_1"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id":"1",
        "child": {
            "id": "1_1",
            "child": {
                "id": "1_1_2",
                "child": {
                    "id": "1_1_2_1"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id":"1",
        "child": {
            "id": "1_2",
            "child": {
                "id": "1_2_1",
                "child": {
                    "id": "1_2_1_1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I tried different options using recursion but didn't find a way to achieve this

Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. I added constructors to your two classes and print methods, so to get a quick idea what the nested structure contains.

```
public class Main {
    static private class Child {
        private String id;
        private List<Child> children;

        Child(String id, Child... children) {
            this.id = id;
            this.children = new ArrayList<Child>();
            for (Child child : children)
                this.children.add(child);
        }
        
        void print() {
            print("");
        }
        
        void print(String tab) {
            System.out.println(tab + id);
            for (Child child : children) child.print(tab + "  ");
        }
    }

    private static class CustomChild {
        private String id;
        private CustomChild child;

        CustomChild(String id, CustomChild child) {
            this.id = id;
            this.child = child;
        }

        void print() {
            print("");
        }
        
        void print(String tab) {
            System.out.println(tab + id);
            if (child != null) child.print(tab + "  ");
        }
    }

    private static List<CustomChild> convert(Child node) {
        List<CustomChild> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if (node.children.isEmpty()) {
            result.add(new CustomChild(node.id, null));
        }
        for (Child child : node.children) {
            for (CustomChild newChild : convert(child)) {
                result.add(new CustomChild(node.id, newChild));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child tree = 
            new Child("1",
                new Child("1_1",
                    new Child("1_1_1"),
                    new Child("1_1_2",
                        new Child("1_1_2_1")
                    )
                ),
                new Child("1_2",
                    new Child("1_2_1",
                        new Child("1_2_1_1")
                    )
                )
            );
        System.out.println("original tree:");
        tree.print();
        System.out.println("converted forest:");
        List<CustomChild> paths = convert(tree);
        for (CustomChild node : paths) {
            node.print();
        } 
    }
}
```

The `main` function creates the input structure that you gave as example and calls `convert` to produce the target list of paths from it.

This is the output the above produces:

```
original tree:
1
  1_1
    1_1_1
    1_1_2
      1_1_2_1
  1_2
    1_2_1
      1_2_1_1
converted forest:
1
  1_1
    1_1_1
1
  1_1
    1_1_2
      1_1_2_1
1
  1_2
    1_2_1
      1_2_1_1
```